# Issues in reducing notice period

Tags: resignation, human-resources, manager, india, relieving-letter

I resigned at this company at the first week of February, my present company notice period is 2 months. My date of joining at the new company is March 25.

I spoke to HR to relieve me early for which she agreed, but says she needs an approval from my reporting manager.

My reporting manager says once he finds my replacement and if i have finished all my tasks only than he can consider relieving me, but mean while i am getting lot of work, so it looks like i wont be re leaved early.

If i get assigned to lot of work i will not be able to finish the work before March 25.

How to do handle this situation?

Comment: Well the questions I've seen have been India related, and a google search doesn't find me any non India references, but happy to be corrected if required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I resigned at this company at the first week of February, my present
>   company notice period is 2 months. My date of joining at the new
>   company is March 25.

Obviously, that was a mistake. You should have agreed to a starting date that was 2 months or more after your resignation date.

> My reporting manager says once he finds my replacement and if i have
>   finished all my tasks only than he can consider relieving me, but mean
>   while i am getting lot of work, so it looks like i wont be re leaved
>   early.
>
> If i get assigned to lot of work i will not be able to finish the work
>   before March 25.

One choice is to work harder to finish all the tasks that are assigned to you, and hope your manager finds a replacement quickly.

But you might be better served to contact your new company, explain what HR and your manager said, and see if you can have your start date pushed into April. They may do so, and still tell you that you can start sooner if things work out correctly at your current company.

Don't wait, call them today.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to apologise to your new employers and work with them to set a realistic start date, rather than one you were contractually unable to fulfil.

Never, ever make assumptions about things being agreed to in your favour - you have a two month notice period, so your start date should never have been set earlier than two months from you handing your notice in.

Your current employer has no benefit in allowing you to exit early, so why assume they would release you early?

Comment: While I agree with your first two paragraphs, I dispute that the employer has no benefit in releasing you before the notice period. Who would want a disgruntled employee to stick around and infect the rest of the staff?  A two month notice period is just stupid for the company, the new person won't be on board because he will have a similar notice period and the person leaving gets to be unhappy and make others feel less than satisfied for two months, It's a morale killer. Only an idiotic company would insist you stay. Which is not to say there aren't plenty of idiotic companies out there.